# Forcing template to have onecolum layout

Tags: two-column

I am writing a paper using [this template](https://www.aamas2024-conference.auckland.ac.nz/calls/submission-instruction/). By default, it uses a two-column layout and there is no one-column option.

If I use `\onecolumn` before `\maketitle` nothing happens. If I use it after it, it breaks the page: the first page has the title, then the first section starts at the second page.

```
\documentclass[sigconf,nonacm]{aamas} % there is no "onecolumn" option

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}

\title[xxx]{xxx}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\onecolumn % doesn't do anything

\maketitle 

\onecolumn % title is in the first page, then Introduction starts in the next page

\section{Introduction}

This document explains the main features of the `\texttt{aamas}' 
document class, which is essentially identical to the `\texttt{acmart}'
document class provided by the ACM. The only difference is a minor 
modification to allow for the correct copyright attribution to IFAAMAS.
For detailed documentation of the original document class, please refer
to the relevant website maintained by the~ACM:

\begin{Definition}
This should also spawn across the whole page, but it does not. 
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\onecolumn` always inserts a pagebreak. As a quick fix you could try loading `multicol` package and begin a `multicolumn` environment with only one column after `\maketitle`. Otherwise, you've to investigate your template. If you ask question regarding a class template which is not on CTAN, you should provide the particular code (parts) yourself. To expect that others will download and test the template will simply lower the chance of getting an answer ;)

Comment: Try to replace document option `sigconf` with `manuscript`.

Comment: @lukeflo Thanks for your reply. `manuscript` and other options are one-column but change the fontsize, fontstyle, margins, spacing, ... I need to have everything the same as `sigconf` BUT one-column. 
I wasn't sure if I should add the whole `cls` here, it feels too cumbersome (it's a long file). 
Anyway, at least I learned that `\onecolumn` always inserts a pagebreak, I didn't know it! 
`multicol` after `maketitle` hides the title and the column spawns across only 1/3 of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!!  Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** after comment.

Try this code using `\hsize=\textwidth` after `\maketitle` or after`\begin{figure}` or after `\begin{table}` and

```
\global\@ACM@balancefalse
```

in the preamble to prevent `\balance` from acting.

Optionally put `\appto{\@floatboxreset}{\hsize=\textwidth}`, in the preamble, just after `\global\@ACM@balancefalse`. It will work on all the floats.

Restore the two column format (on a new page) using

```
   \clearpage       
    \hsize=\columnwidth
```

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[sigconf,nonacm]{aamas} % there is no "onecolumn" option

%********************  added 
\makeatletter
    \global\@ACM@balancefalse 
    %\appto{\@floatboxreset}{\hsize=\textwidth} % OPTIONAL it will work with all the floats
\makeatother
%******************

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}

\title[xxx]{xxx}

\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    
    \maketitle 
    
    \hsize=\textwidth % added for one column <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    This document explains the main features of the `\texttt{aamas}' 
    document class, which is essentially identical to the `\texttt{acmart}'
    document class provided by the ACM. The only difference is a minor 
    modification to allow for the correct copyright attribution to IFAAMAS.
    For detailed documentation of the original document class, please refer
    to the relevant website maintained by the~ACM:
    
    \begin{Definition}
        This should also spawn across the whole page, but it does not. 
    \end{Definition}

    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \hsize=\textwidth %added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{The 23rd International Conference on Autonomous Agents and Multiagent Systems.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \hsize=\textwidth% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \caption{Locations of the first five editions of AAMAS}
        \label{tab:locations}
        \begin{tabular}{rll}\toprule
            \textit{Year} & \textit{City} & \textit{Country} \\ \midrule
            2002 & Bologna & Italy \\
            2003 & Melbourne & Australia \\
            2004 & New York City & USA \\
            2005 & Utrecht & The Netherlands \\
            2006 & Hakodate & Japan \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works for sections but theorems and figures still spawns over half page (as if they'd follow the two-column layout). And thier text overlaps with the regular text of sections. I have edited my question to include a theorem.

Comment: Looks less like a hack than my answer, and thus, should be the preferred solution. Finally, somebody had mercy and taken a deeper look inside the template ;)

Comment: Thanks this works! Is there a way to set `\hsize` globally for all figures, tables, ... instead of locally?

Comment: @Simon Add `\appto{\@floatboxreset}{\hsize=\textwidth}`. It will work with all the floats.

Comment: Uhm, not working. And `floatboxreset` just appears as regular text.

Comment: @Simon See my code. `\appto{\@floatboxreset}{\hsize=\textwidth} ` goes after `\global\@ACM@balancefalse`  , between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Since you're using a custom template, it should be a real possibility to edit the `aamas.cls` file itself.

If you're running GNU/Linux or MacOS, open your terminal, change dir to the directory where you've saved the `aamas.cls` file and run the following command:

```bash
$ sed -e 's/\\twocolumn\[\\box\\mktitle@bx\]/\\box\\mktitle@bx\\par/g' aamas.cls
```

This should replace the `\twocolumn` options of the different styles with the one column version of e.g. `manuscript` without altering other settings.

If you're using Windows (I don't know PowerShell good enough for such a script on the fly) or don't feel comfortable working with a shell, you can open the file with any texteditor, search for the mentioned line and change it by hand (without escaping the backslashes and bracktes, of course).

After that, all styles of the class should use one column layout.

*PS*: I just tested the regex myself and didn't compile the file since I've only taken a look into the `aamas.cls` file and didn't download it. Eventually, you've to adapt some figures afterwards, but generally it should work.

Comment: That kinda works (I don't know why I didn't think about it myself :D). Everything is one-column but I get lots of `Package xkeyval Error: XXX undefined in families aamas_onecol.cls.` (where XXX is urlbreakonhyphens, natbib, review, ...). 
The only place where `\twocolumn` is used is `\def\@printtopmatter` where there is at some point `\twocolumn[\box\mktitle@bx]%`. One-column options have instead `\box\mktitle@bx\par`, which is what you also suggested to use. Changing `\twocolumn` to this causes the errors (but everything is one-column).

Comment: Hm. As I said, I didn't test it and also didn't track all dependencies inside the `.cls` file, because thats really much work. Maybe move a backup copy of the class to another directory and keep the original title `aamas.cls` instead of renaming it to `aamas_onecol.cls`. But now I'm just guessing to be honest.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. No worries, I'll figure it out!